# Cannot find module 'react-dom' from '../../node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/node_modules/react-redux/lib/utils/reactBatchedUpdates.js'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I use redux toolkit query to fetch the data.
I have the following import in my React-Native application:

`import {createApi} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';`

The application works fine, and data is fetching well, but the tests are failing with the following error:

`Cannot find module 'react-dom' from '../../node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/node_modules/react-redux/lib/utils/reactBatchedUpdates.js'`

But when I import from the following:

`import {createApi} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query';`

everything works fine for the tests.

The relevant package versions are:

```
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
"@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
"@types/jest-when": "^2.7.2",
"@types/react": "^17.0.39",
"@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
"babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
"jest": "^27.0.5",
"jest-junit": "^12.2.0",
"jest-when": "^3.2.0",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-redux": "8.0.2",
```

This is a shared package in a Lerna monorepo setup.
Does anyone know what could be wrong here, what could lead to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

React-Redux has to import `batch` from whatever React reconciler you're using - either ReactDOM, or React Native.  It does this by having two different files to import from, and relying on the bundler to find the `batch.native.js` file if you're using React Native.

My guess is that something about your build setup is not finding that file, and so React-Redux is defaulting to importing the file that uses ReactDOM instead.

Unfortunately I don't have any immediate answers on how to fix this, but hopefully that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the answer. The issue is that store is placed like a shared library for the react and react-native application. I got this solved by nohoisting redux toolkit and adding react-dom to the store library, but this isn't ideal since react-native does not need this react-dom library. Is there any preferred way of writing the tests for the shared code? It works well when using it in the app since the store will be used inside of the react or react-native project and it will find the required files and libs, but when testing it I'm not sure how to do it properly.

Comment: Not sure I have an immediate answer. Somehow your RN-related test setup  would need to be configured to pick up `batchedUpdates.native.js` from inside `react-redux`, same as the actual RN bundler would do when you build the app.